# Set optional parameters default value based on other parameters

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I want to achieve following scenario:

Method:

```
public void Process(Request request, string statusCode=request.statusCode, string statusVal=request.statusVal) 
{ 
... 
}
```

Obviously above construct does not work in C#.

So in this case method process takes 3 parameters where calling parameter may or may not pass statusCode and/or statusVal in arguments.

When the values are not passed it should take the values from request object as default value. In short can the default value of optional parameters be dynamic or based on another compulsory parameter.

Comment: This is when you go back to good old method overloading and just do `public void Process(Request request) { Process(request, request.statusCode, request.statusVal);}`

Comment: What about a method overload that provide requried params and then execute the actual function?

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can use optional parameters as described:

```
public void Process(Request request, string statusCode = null, string statusVal= null) 
{ 
    statusCode = statusCode ?? request.statusCode;
    statusVal = statusVal ?? request.statusVal;
    ... 
}
```

Now you can call it any of these ways:

- `Process(request);`
- `Process(request, "code");`
- `Process(request, "code", "val");`
- `Process(request, statusCode: "code");`
- `Process(request, statusVal: "val");`

Comment: The one thing to note here is that `Process(request)` will be the same as `Process(request, null, null)` where as if you could have dynamic optional parameters they'd be different.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use optional parameters like this. That's why I would suggest overloading the method. Could be look like this.

```
public void Process(Request request) 
{ 
    Process(request, request.statusCode, request.statusVal);
}

public void Process(Request request, string statusCode, string statusVal) 
{ 
    //your logic
}
```

In this case you can call the method with the `Request` only or specific `statusCode` and `statusVal` and both will have the same logic.

For further information have a look at [C# in Depth: Overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)